# I need a simple way to backup files to Amazon glacier from the command line?

Tags: command-line, backup, ruby, amazon-glacier

I have a CentOS server online with a directory of cPmove files I need to back up to Amazon Glacier.  I only have command line access, no GUI.

I need a command line client that is relatively easy to use to upload the files. For example I have used dropbox_uploader.sh before ( https://github.com/andreafabrizi/Dropbox-Uploader ) with this simple bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
find /backup_folder -maxdepth 1 -name "cpmove-*.tar.gz" | while read CPMOVE
do
   ./dropbox_uploader.sh upload ${CPMOVE}
done
```

I saw this one:
https://github.com/carlossg/glacier-cli
but I don't have java installed on the server and am a bit hesistant to install it, due to all the security issues lately.

I do have python and ruby:

```
me@server [/home]# python -V
Python 2.4.3
root@server [/home]# ruby --version
ruby 1.8.7 (2012-06-29 patchlevel 370) [i686-linux]
me@server [/home]#
```

Is there a ruby (preferable) or python or other language (less preferable) amazon glacier command line client?)

Comment: Sorry, I had not looked into Glacier in depth, I thought you had normal ssh access. Answer deleted.

Comment: I have since found out that I can upload to s3 with ruby's fog gem. Then, from s3's aws management console, I can set an expiration policy and have the files archived to glacier. Works. Also, fog supports Glacier directly but I haven't looked into that yet. For anyone that's curious, here's my ruby script for uploading to s3: https://gist.github.com/ivanoats/4712421

Answer (score 11):

The canonical library for interfacing with AWS via Python is [Boto](https://github.com/boto/boto3). Though it is intended to be used as a library in a Python script, it is simple enough to use independently. You can skim [the fine documentation](http://boto3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/guide/quickstart.html), and [this page](http://queirozf.com/entries/interacting-with-amazon-glacier-on-ubuntu-file-uploads-and-more) has an overview of how to use Boto, but here are the important parts:

Put your AWS credentials in `~/.boto`:

```
[Credentials]
aws_access_key_id = FOO
aws_secret_access_key = BAR
```

List your vaults:

```
$ glacier vaults
```

Upload a file:

```
$ glacier upload foo-vault foo.zip
```

List pending jobs on a particular vault:

```
$ glacier jobs foo-vault
```

Though it really isn't easier to use than Boto itself, [Amazon Glacier CLI Interface](https://github.com/uskudnik/amazon-glacier-cmd-interface) is based on Boto and is in fact designed for end users. [Here](http://blog.tkassembled.com/326/creating-long-term-backups-with-amazon-glacier-on-linux/) is a tutorial for it.

Lastly the official [AWS-CLI](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-using-glacier.html) is rather easy to use. [Put the credentials](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/glacier/upload-archive.html) in `~/.aws/credentials` and then simply use these commands:

Create a vault:

```
$ aws glacier create-vault --account-id - --vault-name foo-vault
```

[Upload](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/glacier/upload-archive.html) a file:

```
$ aws glacier upload-archive --account-id - --vault-name foo-vault --body foo.zip
```

Comment: funny thing is your step `upload-archive` is not even covered in the shoddy documentation at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-services-glacier.html

Comment: These instructions will only work if your vault is in the default region for boto (us-east-1). Otherwise, you need specify the region. E.g. if your vault is in CA, the command should be  `aws glacier vaults --region us-west-1`.

Answer (score 6):

[github.com/numblr/glaciertools](https://github.com/numblr/glaciertools) provides bash scripts that orchestrate the mulitpart upload of a large file with the official AWS command line client ([AWS CLI](https://aws.amazon.com/documentation/cli/)). This is useful in the case when your data exceeds the 4GB limit for uploading an archive in a single operation with the AWS CLI.

To use the scripts you need to have the AWS CLI installed and setup, which requires python. The link contains additional information about the setup.

Then you can create an archive of your backup and upload it to a vault on glacier with

```
> ./glacierupload -v myvault /path/to/my/archive
```

More detailed information is contained in the [documentation](https://github.com/numblr/glaciertools/blob/master/README.md) there.

Answer (score 4):

Try [vsespb/mt-aws-glacier](https://github.com/vsespb/mt-aws-glacier) – Perl multithreaded multipart sync to Amazon Glacier with easy deploy instructions for CentOS.

Answer (score 3):

There is another software also named **glacier-cli** (https://github.com/basak/glacier-cli) but in python that seems to work pretty well.